Eziriz - Intellilock can't create a valid license
I've been reading an online user guide of intellilock but I don't understand how to create a valid license file.
My steps:

I referenced intellilock.dll in my C# project

I retrieve HD ID using this code:
(IntelliLock.Licensing.HardwareID.GetHardwareID(true, true, true, true, true, true);)

To check license status I used this code:
 private bool IsValidLicenseAvailable()
 {
     return (EvaluationMonitor.CurrentLicense.LicenseStatus == IntelliLock.Licensing.LicenseStatus.Licensed);
 }


Then I start intellilock software

I've added my assembly

On the lock setting page I've set runtime = 1

On the protection settings page, I set "obfuscation" and "control flow obfuscation"

On the finalization page --> GO button (to create a pack of my application + intellilock .dll)


Now, when running my app, I'm able to read a System ID and license demo mode. All may be ok
What is the next step to make a valid license file to unlock my application?
I open the tab license generator; then I set the checkbox hardware lock license and input the System ID retrieve from my assembly.
Then I create a license and copy in the same folder of my assembly.
Unfortunately the application still to launch in demo mode.
Thanks a lot
